# Freeform not sending with DXF / DWG but does with other extensions

Tags: solspace-freeform, ee5, solspace-freeform-next

The idea is that visitors can upload a DWG or DXF file using freeform. So we can make a calculation for them. But issue is, that Freeform is sending and saving the submissions while uploading PDF / DOC / JPG etc. etc. But when sending DWG / DXF it won't save and won't e-mail. It's just refreshing to it's own page.

Contacted Solspace about it, but they said i'm doing something wrong. All extensions are allowed and also uploading DWG / DXF in filemanager / assets is working fine. So it must be a issue in freeform?!

Thanks in advance!

W.

```
                    {exp:freeform_next:form form_id="2" return="/contact/bedankt"}


                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-2">
                        <label for="naam">Naam</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="naam" placeholder="Uw naam"/>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-2">
                        <label for="bedrijfsnaam">Bedrijfsnaam</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="bedrijfsnaam" placeholder="Uw bedrijfsnaam"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-2">
                        <label for="telefoon">Telefoon</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="telefoon" placeholder="Uw telefoonnummer"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-2">
                        <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-10">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Uw naam"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-2">
                        <label for="bericht">Bestand</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-10">
                        {field:bestand:render_input}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-2">
                        <label for="bericht">Bericht</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-10">
                        <textarea class="form-control" name="bericht" placeholder="Uw bericht" rows="6"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-10 offset-xl-2">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Versturen">
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/exp:freeform_next:form}
```

Answer (score 0):

If memory serves me, you may need to add those mime types to the mimes.php file
It's buried in /system/ee/EllisLab/ExpressionEngine/Config/mimes.php

Comment: Thought so to. But that was not it. Freeform itself didn't accept the extension. I was already able to upload the files in CP before. See comment above what solution was. Thanks a lot for your replies.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for response, don't think that's the issue. Because when using assets or EE's default filemanager it will upload without any problem. To be certain I have added these mimes already. Without positive result.

Solspace Support told me the same, but it's not an EE issue I guess. Because EE can handle the DXF, but only issue is sending it by Solspace freeform next.[image]

Comment: Next, question: how are you sending the email? via service? php? if service, it may be blocked there. Can you turn on debug/error reporting mode and see if you can get any feedback? Have you tried sending an email from the control panel with a .dwg attachment?

Comment: I got a reply from Solspace, this was an issue that was in the module. They configured a feature to add extensions by the config file. The mimes where already added to expression engine. And now also to freeform itself. So it's working like a charm. I think they will release it in the new version aswell.